# In F# when should I use List.choose and when to use List.filter

Tags: f#

I have just been doing a CodeWars exercise - "create a function that takes a list of non-negative integers and strings and returns a new list with the strings filtered out".

My solution used List.filter and it failed for one of the edge cases.  So I looked at their solution and it used List.choose - which seemed to pretty much identical to my version except it converted the result to an option before deciding whether to include it in the new list.

I am confused - please can someone explain when it is best to use 'choose' and when it is best to use 'filter'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you have already observed the essence of the answer: `filter` allows you to test for a condition, but with `choose` you can also project your value in the same expression, which would take a separate `map` if using `filter`.

Since the problem statement isn't clear (a list cannot contain integer and strings at the same time, except when they are boxed; i.e. the type of the list would be `obj list`), we can look at both scenarios. Note the additional `map` functions when using `filter`.

```
// List of strings that may contain integer representations
["1"; "abc"; "2"; "def"]
|> List.choose (System.Int32.TryParse >> function
| true, i -> Some i
| _ -> None )

["1"; "abc"; "2"; "def"]
|> List.map System.Int32.TryParse
|> List.filter fst
|> List.map snd
```

Both expressions return `int list = [1; 2]`.

```
// List of object that are either of type int or of type string
[box 1; box "abc"; box 2; box "def"]
|> List.choose (function
| :? int as i -> Some i
| _ -> None )

[box 1; box "abc"; box 2; box "def"]
|> List.filter (fun i -> i :? int)
|> List.map unbox<int>
```

In the case of `obj list` as input the projection serves to provide the correct result type. That might be done in a different way, e.g. with an annotated let binding.

In the end, the decision between the two is down to your personal preferences.

Comment: Perfect - thank you.  The problem involved a boxed list as per your second suggestion but it is really helpful to see it all worked through and explained.

Answer (score 4):

`List.choose` is strictly more general than `List.filter`. You can implement `List.filter` using only `List.choose`, but not the other way around. You should use `List.choose` in place of `List.filter` only when you can't use the latter because it's simpler and describes your intention more accurately.

You can observe this difference pretty much from the type signatures alone.

```ml
List.choose : ('T -> 'U option) -> 'T list -> 'U list
List.filter : ('T -> bool) -> 'T list -> 'T list
```

`List.filter` can be implemented with `List.choose` like this:

```ml
let filter : ('T -> bool) -> 'T list -> 'T list =
  fun predicate ->
    List.choose (fun x -> if predicate x then Some x else None)
```

`List.choose` can however be implemented (inefficiently) using `List.filter` *along with* `List.map` and `Option.get' (it is in fact called`filterMap` in many languages and libraries):

```ml
let choose : ('T -> 'U option) -> 'T list -> 'U list =
  fun f list ->
    list
      |> List.map f
      |> List.filter (fun x -> x <> None)
      |> List.map Option.get
```

Note that `Option.get` can raise an exception, but won't here because we've filtered out the `None`s that would cause that. But because it is unsafe, it's easy to make a mistake and because this implementation is not very efficient, it's nice to have `List.choose` come out-of-the-box.